# LayoutInflater not working on below 4.3 devices when i use Appcompat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, layout-inflater

I am developing app which support lollipop as well as other versions of android.I am using Toolbar along with DrawerLayout. DrawerLayout view is customized view not a listview. I used below code for inflate row of DrawerLayout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null,true);
```

Its working fine on lollipop but not working on other versions. **Giving exception**

```
01-29 10:14:52.761: I/(26053): Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-29 10:14:52.761: W/ResourceType(26053): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020082 (t=1 e=130) in package 0 (error -75)
```

Comment: problem is in xml so post `table_row.xml` file

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i found problem.. actually i set ripple background to table row because of that it giving me exception now problem is resolved. Thanks :)